# REGEX in javascript not working for dots (.) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using a regex to validate an email address in JavaScript.

The regex is pretty simple. It checks three things: 1)'@' ,  2)'.' ('dot' as in **something@gmail.com**), and 3) 'a-z' in an email address. If all three return true, email address is valid (according to my validation, atleast)

Here is the code:

```
function checkemail(){
  var e = document.getElementById("email").value;
  if((e.match(/@/g)==null)||(e.match(/[a-z]/ig)==null)||(e.match(/./g)==null)){
  //display error message
  }
}
```

My question is:

```
(e.match(/./g)==null); //returns false even though there are no dots in the string e
```

**returns false even when there are no dots in string.**

For example:

```
("thisIsMyEmail".match(/./ig))==null //returns false
```

**Why does it return false when it should be true?**

Comment: periods are special in a regex, it means "any character", not just a period, to make it mean a period, it has to be escaped.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: Instead of using `match` for literal strings, you should use `String.prototype.indexOf()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/./g` (or `/./ig`) will match any string that as at least one character in it. `.` is special in regular expressions, it means "any character here."

For an *actual* dot, escape it with a backslash: `/\./g`.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you don't need to check if the string is null.  Simply use this:

```js
var email = "Godisgood@gmail.com";

if (email.match(/^\S+\@\S+\.\S+$/i)){
alert("Email address passed validation.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It does pretty much the same as mine. It does not seem to check for letters after the final dot. Eg: bob@gmail. returns true. But it helps. Thanks

Comment: @raneshu, I'm sorry, my code was a bit messy.  Try it now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
(e.match(/\./g)==null);
```

`.` matches any character so needs escaping `/\./g`

Answer (score 1):

you have to escape the `.`
The unescaped period means matches any character.

Meaning having a string "abc" using your expression would result in an array containing the characters 'a', 'b', and 'c'.

In your snippet the correct answer is

```
(e.match(/\./g)==null);
```

This should result to what you're expecting

Answer (score 0):

I know you have already got the answer.

But I just want to give an advice.
My advice is - don't use the javascript code to validate any email address; because as per your code, **@domain.**, **@domain.com** these all are also valid email, but everybody knows these are not a valid email address.

So use the below code:

```js
let email = $(this).val();
var positionOfAt = email.indexOf("@");
var positionOfDot = email.lastIndexOf(".");

if(email.search("@") == -1 || //if '@' is not present
email.search(" ") >= 1 || //if blank space is present
email.search(".") == -1 || //if "." is not present
positionOfAt < 1 || //if there is no character before "@", at least one character should be present before "@"
positionOfDot - positionOfAt <= 2 || //between '@' and '.', if there is not at least two character
email.length - positionOfDot <= 2) //if after '.' there is not at least two character)
{
    console.log("Invalid email id")
}
else
{
    console.log("Valid email id")
}
```